# Create a customized installer like Anaconda, with Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to encapsulate my python environment so it can be used on different maachines. For the purpose I did use pipenv and it works fine.

Now I discovered Anaconda, and I found the idea brilliant: you can download the installer (pkg or win installer), and it will do everything you do by hand, while installing the virtualenv, activate it and even set up a Jupyter  interface.

Is there a procedure that allow users to implement the same, using Conda,  so a user just download the package, instead of dealing with terminal and such? I have to deploy my environment on machines where users are not that proficient with terminal, and having a single installer that does everything  would save me time to actually configure the environment

Comment: It's not perfectly clear what are you asking. If your question "How can I use conda with pipenv?" - answer is in pipenv documentation - [4.2.7 Pipenv and Other Python Distributions](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pipenv/latest/pipenv.pdf)

Comment: Sorry; my question is how can I achieve what Anaconda does, but using my own packages.

Comment: The goal of anaconda AFAIK is to provide highly optimized libraries but revisiting your question: "I have to deploy my environment on machines where users are not that proficient with terminal" I see that you're asking about packaging your work. That raises a lot of other questions: Do you need to support Linux/MacOS/Windows? Which format do you prefer: self-contained executable, OS installation package, python package, anaconda package?

Comment: Thanks for raising these points. I need to support both OSX and Windows. Ideally I write my code and wrap everything in an installer like Anaconda, then give these users the package/installer and they are good to go and execute code in that environment, after performing installation

Comment: I don't know all your requirements but I would try to: a) create python package compatible with pipenv (maybe with conda), b) make a fancy installer combining python/conda installer and pipenv script, c) offline version if needed

Comment: containers, perhaps

Comment: So there is no way to make something like the guys that made anaconda did, in an easy way? I guess that the easiest thing is to just piggyback on their installer, and then make a script that update their environment. It will be bloated and full of useless packages, but I guess it is an easy way to get everything in one single installer. Thanks for the pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### (conda) constructor

The description for the package **constructor** matches your use case almost to the word:

> constructor is a tool which allows constructing an installer for a collection of conda packages. Basically, it creates an Anaconda-like installer consisting of conda packages.

See [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/conda/constructor) for more details.

One still needs to build a separate installer *per architecture* (no `noarch` support), but [the example they provide](https://github.com/conda/constructor/tree/master/examples/maxiconda) makes it seem rather straight-forward.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will look into this and give it a try