# Export Anaconda enviroment with packages

Tags: package, anaconda, conda, environment

How can I export an Anaconda enviroment with all the packages in them? When I export the env using the `conda export` utility, I get a .yml file. When I load it to recreate an env, it downloads the packages again ( which go upto 220 MB ).

> So, is there any way to export the env in such a way, where the
>   packages go with it in one file. It then only loads the packages
>   instead of downloading them again.

Any help, suggestion or trick would be welcomed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a customized installer like Anaconda, with Conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487292/create-a-customized-installer-like-anaconda-with-conda)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But, it could not understand that what are exactly doing when we are creating an installer like Anaconda. I would like some more explanation as I am new to this.

Comment: the installer would bundle the tarballs cached in the `pkgs/` subdirectory and create a single script that would recreate the specific environment without the need for redownloading those packages. As with most things, running [their example](https://github.com/conda/constructor/tree/master/examples/maxiconda) should help you better understand what it does and how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @merv do you have any idea on this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54688432/10878733) of mine related with the same ( conda installers ).